# Нужна помощь. В верстке.(сss, html)

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Здраствуйте, у меня возникла такая проблема.
Есть картинка в которой нужно сделать обтекание по левому краю, при этом под картинкой должна быть подпись( как должно быть видно в приклеплённой фотографии).
Я знаю как это сделать используя два элемента div, а можно ли это сделать с одним таким элементом, чтобы не писать лишний код[image: Как должно быть]

Answer (score 0):

Такие подписи (не только к картинкам) правильно делать при помощи элемента `<figure>`. Выглядеть это будет так:

```
<figure>
  <img src="" alt="">
  <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Чтобы текст обтекал картинку, используйте для неё свойство `float`. Но учтите, что если высота текста будет меньше высоты обтекаемой картинки, то она будет некрасиво вылазить за границы контейнера (фиксится clearfix'ом). Пример:

```
.float-right: {
  float: right;
}
```